# my phone was najis for a long time

Tags: taharah, najis

i have this bad habit of taking my phone to the bathroom today i thought about it how my phone may be impure  because after i wash my part and dry it with a tissue some urine is on the tissue and i might have touched it then touched my phone but today i’m sure i touched urine then my phone i cleaned my phone and my hands i didn’t know my phone had to be pure and sometimes i prayed with my phone in front of me and my head touched it or i prayed with it in my pocket should i repent for this or disregard it

Comment: Please stop re-posting similar questions

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you in the simplest way I can.

First of all, whenever you take your cell phone to the bathroom I'm sure you do not touch it with your hand right after you have cleaned your waste with the very same hands.

Secondly, just taking anything with you in the bathroom doesn't make it impure. If that was true then we would be instructed to also change our clothes and scrub ourselves thoroughly every time we come out of the bathroom.

Comment: after i poured the water i dried my hands then used tissue to remove excess urine so when i was holding the tissue to my part the urine touched my finger because i was holding it close to where the urine comes out as to squeeze out the excess and i touched my phone i did this today but as for other days i’m unsure

Comment: If it is the case and you hold your phone so close then it is better not to use the phone while peeing. It just takes seconds to pee. Just not using phone for such short time won't do any harm to you..

Comment: but are my prayers valid that’s my main question

Comment: If it all happened unintentionally and you thought of it afterwards then it's okay. May Allah accept your prayers.

Comment: i’ve decided i will repent inshallah

Comment: Very pleased to hear that brother  :)